# How to separate same applications with different position in taskbar Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, application-launch

Is there any way to use applications like that is a different application and when opening it will open in a different position in the taskbar not like in the same application with Other Instances Preview.

I don't like this :
[Image Same Applications Preview At Single Place on taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uXfU.jpg)

sorry for this image because I'm not able to take a screenshot of my windows 11 whenever I try to take a screenshot it will automatically go on hover.

Any help will be always appreciated! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move icons on the taskbar to different positions, which is I think what you are asking.

This is the native behavior that is available.

If you wish an application to do this for you, you need a third party app. I am not aware of an app that will do this.

So stick with the native behavior and arrange your icons as you need. That is what I do if I wish to move an icon "out of the way"

You may need to ungroup icons if you are trying to re-arrange icons of the same app.

If your apps do not ungroup, it may be dependent on the app and you may need to adapt to the given behavior.

Comment: @Jhon how can I do ungroup ?

Comment: For Windows 10, task bar settings, and adjust Combine task bar items to Never.

Comment: @Jhon But still they stick together!

Comment: For normal apps, not here - tested on my Windows 10 machine. You may need to adapt to the given behavior for the apps you have.

Comment: @Jhon yeah u are right